# " Expected '(' but got identifier " & " Parse error: mismatched input '{' expecting {';', '='} [undefined] "

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract CrowdFunding 
{
    
    struct Investor
    {
        address addr;
        uint amount;
    }
    
    address public owner;       
    uint public NumOfInvestors; 
    uint public deadline;       
    string public status;       
    bool public isOver;         
    uint public goalAmount;     
    uint public totalAmount;    
    mapping (uint => Investor) public investors; 
    
    modifier onlyOwner () 
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    
    function crowdfunding(uint _duration, uint _goalAmount) public
    {
        owner == msg.sender;
        deadline = now + _duration;
        
        goalAmount = _goalAmount;
        status = "Funding";
        isOver = "false";
        NumOfInvestors = 0;
        totalAmount = 0;
    }
    
    
    function fund() payable public
    {
       
        require(!isOver);
        
        Investor inv = investors[NumOfInvestors++]; 
        inv.addr = msg.sender;                      
        inv.amount = msg.value;                     
        totalAmount += inv.amount;
    }
    
   
    function checkGoalReached () public onlyOwner 
    {
        
        
        require(!isOver);
        
        
        require(now >= deadline);
        
        if(totalAmount >= goalAmount) 
        {  
            status = "Campaign succeeded.";
            isOver = true;
            
            
            if(!owner.send(this.balance)) 
            {
                throw;
            }
            else 
            { 
                
                uint i = 0;
                status = "Campaign Failed.";
                isOver = true;
                
                while (i <= NumOfInvestors) 
                {
                    
                    if(!investors[i].addr.send(investors[i].amount)) 
                    {
                        throw;   
                    }
                    
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        function kill() public onlyOwner 
        {
            selfdestrct(owner);
        }

    }
}
```

I wrote a contract but got errors in the first and second lines of function kill().

It shows " Expected '(' but got identifier" at the first line, and " Parse error: mismatched input '{' expecting { ';' , '=' } [undefined] " at the second line.

I double-checked my code structure and also read some articles from StackOverflow.

For the problems shows in the first line, those articles said that might miss a "{" or "}". But I didn't miss for sure. (If I really missed them I'm a damn fool.

As to the problem shows in the second line, I just can't tell why it's wrong.
Would it be a version issue??

Pls help me. Beg for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
        function kill() public onlyOwner 
        {
            selfdestrct(owner);
        }
```

Inside of another function, move it outside, and everything will works. Please, check closing brakets `}`.
Also You will want to fix the typo `selfdestruct`

Here is working code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract CrowdFunding 
{
    
    struct Investor
    {
        address payable addr;
        uint amount;
    }
    
    address payable public owner;       
    uint public NumOfInvestors; 
    uint public deadline;       
    string public status;       
    bool public isOver;         
    uint public goalAmount;     
    uint public totalAmount;    
    mapping (uint => Investor) public investors; 
    
    modifier onlyOwner () 
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    
    function crowdfunding(uint _duration, uint _goalAmount) public
    {
        owner == msg.sender;
        deadline = block.timestamp + _duration;
        
        goalAmount = _goalAmount;
        status = "Funding";
        isOver = false;
        NumOfInvestors = 0;
        totalAmount = 0;
    }
    
    
    function fund() payable public
    {
       
        require(!isOver);
        
        Investor storage inv = investors[NumOfInvestors++]; 
        inv.addr = payable(msg.sender);                      
        inv.amount = msg.value;                     
        totalAmount += inv.amount;
    }
    
   
    function checkGoalReached () public onlyOwner 
    {
        
        
        require(!isOver);
        
        
        require(block.timestamp >= deadline);
        
        if(totalAmount >= goalAmount) 
        {  
            status = "Campaign succeeded.";
            isOver = true;
            
            address payable self = payable(address(this));
            uint256 balance = self.balance;
            if(!owner.send(balance)) 
            {
                revert();
            }
            else 
            { 
                
                uint i = 0;
                status = "Campaign Failed.";
                isOver = true;
                
                while (i <= NumOfInvestors) 
                {
                    
                    if(!investors[i].addr.send(investors[i].amount)) 
                    {
                        revert();   
                    }
                    
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        

    }
        function kill() public onlyOwner 
        {
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
}
```

Comment: But I did check my brackets, and they are all in pairs. Can you show me which closing bracket was the one you added?

Comment: yeah, I added working example

Comment: Added example well compiling in remix